# MacOS Safari 11 "prevent cross-site tracking" breaks google sign-in for websites

Tags: safari, google-oauth, google-signin

It would appear that the new Safari cross-site tracking functionality is interfering with Google's OAuth2 implementation (at least in google sign-in for websites). I'm experiencing this issue with a project I'm currently developing, and would appreciate advice from anyone who has ran into the same problem.

Further details:

- With all cache/cookies cleared, the sign-in flow works properly on first login.
- Upon refreshing, entering the sign-in flow recognizes you are already authenticated with the OAuth provider, opens a popup and immediately closes it (this is expected behaviour for already allowed sources).
- after the popup closes, the finality of the auth flow is broken, and silently fails with no errors thrown inside the code, and no logged in user returned.

Unchecking the "prevent cross-site tracking" option allows the sign-in flow to behave as intended.

Comment: you're seeing this issue in iOS Safari, right?

Comment: @mash, MacOS. I've edited the title to be more specific.

Comment: I can see this both in latest macOS and iOS Safari. Maybe something to do with how ITP works and does not appear evident at first sign-in. Interesting things start to happen only after 24 hours later.

Comment: Did you managed to get it working?

Comment: @Claudiu I did not - but I will be picking this up again in a couple weeks with the aim to solve the issue.

Comment: We have a similiar problem with our webpage, where jQuery is not fully loaded (2000 lines missing) only when this option is set to true... To test it just crashes in Safari iOS https://www.additive-net.de/de/

Comment: @Duncan I am having similar issue in safari only. Did you managed to get solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I experienced the same problem with Safari.
In my case, as others reported on the issue you created on GitHub, I was using the redirect flow.

In a recent attempt, I changed the `ux_mode` to `"popup"`, and it worked.

It is really bad that Google left this abandoned for two years.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore if the user opens a new tab or instance of a PWA in iOS. The new Safari cross-site tracking feature seems to block either way.